# PyGeodesy and GeographicLib available in Python 2.7 but not available in Python 3.6

Tags: python

My operating system is Ubuntu MATE 18.04. I would like to use the python packages PyGeodesy and GeographicLib in python 3.6. Right now I can only use those packages in python 2.7. I have run the commands `pip install geographiclib` and `pip install PyGeodesy`. Now I have the following situation:

```
gus@foo:~$ python -i
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pygeodesy
>>> from geographiclib.geodesic import Geodesic
>>> Geodesic.WGS84.Inverse(-41.32, 174.81, 40.96, -5.50)
{'lat1': -41.32, 'a12': 179.6197069334283, 's12': 19959679.26735382, 'lat2': 40.96, 'azi2': 18.825195123247063, 'azi1': 161.06766998616015, 'lon1': 174.81, 'lon2': -5.5}
>>> {'lat1': -41.32,
...  'a12': 179.6197069334283,
...  's12': 19959679.26735382,
...  'lat2': 40.96,
...  'azi2': 18.825195123248392,
...  'azi1': 161.06766998615882,
...  'lon1': 174.81,
...  'lon2': -5.5}
{'azi2': 18.825195123248392, 'azi1': 161.06766998615882, 'lat1': -41.32, 'lon2': -5.5, 'a12': 179.6197069334283, 'lon1': 174.81, 's12': 19959679.26735382, 'lat2': 40.96}
>>> 
gus@foo:~$ python3 -i
Python 3.6.6 (default, Sep 12 2018, 18:26:19) 
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pygeodesy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygeodesy'
>>> import geographiclib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geographiclib'
>>>
```

**UPDATE**
I have attempted the following commands, but the original problem persists.

```
gus@foo:~$ python3 -m pip install geographiclib
Collecting geographiclib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5b/ac/4f348828091490d77899bc74e92238e2b55c59392f21948f296e94e50e2b/geographiclib-1.49.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: geographiclib
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for geographiclib ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/balloonionaire/.cache/pip/wheels/99/45/d1/14954797e2a976083182c2e7da9b4e924509e59b6e5c661061
Successfully built geographiclib
Installing collected packages: geographiclib
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/geographiclib-1.49.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

There is some documentation at https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/, which I think is relevant, but that I don't understand.

Comment: I use geographiclib with Python 3.6. The pip program and module are version-specific. Did you use the right pip when you tried to install geographiclib for Python 3.6? To make sure you're using the right pip, you should use the module, eg `python3 -m pip install geographiclib`

Comment: Please see the update to the OP.